# How to change MDCFilledTextField/MDCOutlinedTextField height?

Tags: ios, swift, material-components-ios

Size of MDCFilledTextField/MDCOutlinedTextField is not changeable and it's fixed.
Any idea to change [Material](https://material.io/components/text-fields/ios#filled-text-field) TextFields height?

FYI: I tested some ways like putting the textField in a view ...et cetera. non of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `font` size changes the `height`!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Material 2 [Docs](https://m2.material.io/components/text-fields/ios#outlined-text-field) the `MDCOutlinedTextField` or `MDCFilledTextArea` size can be adjusted by passing in custom frame dimensions:

```
let estimatedFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CUSTOM_WIDTH, height: CUSTOM_HEIGHT)
let textField = MDCOutlinedTextField(frame: estimatedFrame)
```